# Moveable split screen in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, split

I want to a split able and moveable screen but I m not able to do that i have use react split pane but its not working, the functionality I needed is that when click on the profile icon from list at lower part of screen the data of upper screen is changed accordingly. the following is the sample code that describe what functionality I actually needed you can implement here i will change accordingly

[image]

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component{
     constructor(){
       super();
       this.state={
               name:""
            }
       this.changeDetected=this.changeDetected.bind(this)
       }
        changeDetected(value){
                    this.setState({
                           name:value
                        })
              }

    render(){
       return(
          <Upper_compo data={this.state.name} />
          {*Spliting over here*}
          <Lower_compo changeDetected={this.changeDetected} />
         )
      }
}
export default MainComponent
```

//Upper part of Screen

```
class Upper_compo extends React.component{
   constructor(props){
      super();
      this.state={
          name:props.data
      }
    }



   render(){
       return(
             <>
                <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
             </>
        )
    }
}
export default Upper_compo
```

//Lower part of Screen

```
class Lower_compo extends React.component{
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.state={
      }
    }



   render(){
       return(
             <>
                <input type="text" placeholder="name" onChange={this.props.changeDected(value) />
             </>
        )
    }
}
export default Lower_compo
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to me the problem is in the `Upper_compo` component: there, you save the `name` into the `state` inside the constructor, and then use `this.state.Name` in the render (BTW, it should be `name`, with lowercase `n`).

But, this way, you are not considering the `this.props.name` anymore, thus it will never change.
Since `Upper_compo` does not need to change the `name`, you can just use `this.props.name` inside the `render`of `Upper_compo` instead of `this.state.name`: thank to this, whenever the props `name` changes, the rendered UI of `Upper_compo` will change accordingly.

And, by the way, by keeping the state in the parent component, in your case `MainComponent`, you are doing the so-called **Lifting State Up**: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html which is a totally OK implementation.

EDIT: Alternatively, inside `Upper_compo` you should implement the `getDerivedStateFromProps`: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops, which allows you to update the state based on some change in the props.
Though, I would recommend this way, but the first one I explained.

Comment: i have given this code just for the concept my issue was to create a moveable spilt

Comment: Can help me regarding this issue